# Scheduling a task every n months using Timer Service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, scheduling

I am using the timer service of a Java EE application server (GlassFish), and I want to schedule a task to be executed every n months (every 2 months for example). I've tried to use : 
`scheduleExpression.month(*/2)`. But I get this exception:

> Invalid month value: */2

Comment: what are you using for scheduling? Windows? Unix/Linux? Something else?

Comment: Sorry! I am using the timer service of JEE application server (Glassfish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have to force the user to enter on of these values (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12) to work around the problem. Thus, we can determine the list of months in which the task will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec: Intervals may be set **only** for second, minute, and hour attributes.

But you can use:

```
@Schedule(month="2,4,6,8,10,12")
```

to run your task in month 2 (february), 4 (april) and so on...

Otherwise there is for example

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1")
```

which would run the task on the first of every month.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I've thought about this, but what if we choose to schedule the task every 5 months for example? thus, this solution above is not right.

Comment: The task can start by checking what month it is, and exit without doing any work if it's not the right month.